# Chemical equilibrium

Tags: physical-chemistry, equilibrium

When calculating equilibrium constant with partial pressures if there is a solid involved should we consider it in the total number of moles in mole fraction?

Comment: The phrase 'number of moles' is incorrect, it should be 'amount of substance'.

Answer (score -3):

The answer is No ! Solid have no vapor pressures. And if they still have, this pressure is a constant at the equilibrium conditions. So it does not change between the beginning and the end of the reaction. So it is included in the equilibrium constant.

Comment: This answer is wrong. You should look up sublimation.